# Operadores % y // en Python

Tags: python, funciones

A continuación mostraré un código realizado en Python, y me gustaría que pudieran aclarar mi duda de el por qué se escribe el `%` y el `//`. Muchas gracias y feliz tarde.

```
def sumaDigitos(numero):
    suma=0
    while numero!=0:
        digito=numero%10
        suma=suma+digito
        numero=numero//10
    return suma

 
 sumatoria=0
 num=int(input("Número a procesar: "))
 while num!=0:
    print("Suma:",sumaDigitos(num))
    sumatoria=sumatoria+num
    num=int(input("Número a procesar: "))
print("Sumatoria:", sumatoria)
print("Dígitos:", sumaDigitos(sumatoria))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: `//` - resultado de división entera (cociente). `%` - resto de división entera (resto o residuo). Entre las 2 tenemos una división de esas que hacíamos en la primaria cuando todavía no dábamos decimales. Ver [partes de la división](https://www.google.com/search?q=matematicas+partes+de+division). También hay que reconocer que los nombres de las variables (`digito`, `numero`) no ayudan mucho a la claridad; las mismas deberían dar una pista de qué contienen. Finalmente has una [prueba de escritorio](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+prueba+de+escritorio) y resuelve tus dudas.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, como anexo a la excelente respuesta de aeportugal, te pongo dos ejemplos: ***5 // 2*** devuelve ***2***, osea realiza la división, pero solo retorna la parte entera, ***5 % 2*** devuelve ***1***, hace la misma operación, pero devuelve lo que "sobra"  de la división, osea el resto, esta operación se llama *modulo*.

Answer (score 0):

El algoritmo que muestras opera con un número cada vez más pequeño hasta que ha procesado todas las cifras.
Para sumar cada cifra de forma sucesiva obtiene la cifra de las unidades.
Para hacer eso utiliza el operador módulo `%`.
Según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) devuelve el resto de la división entera del primer argumento entre el segundo.
Como el segundo argumento es 10, esto equivale a tomar la cifra de las unidades.

Como ya ha sumado esta cifra, el algoritmo continúa procesando el número resultante de haber eliminado la cifra de las unidades.
Esto es lo mismo que hacer la división entera, `//`, entre 10.
Esto es así porque haciendo la división entre 10, obtenemos un número con un dígito decimal: el dígito que ya hemos sumado.
Al tomar su parte entera, descartamos esa parte decimal.

Sin embargo Python te permite hacer estas operaciones de una forma mucho más eficiente: sin necesidad de llamar a los dos operadores `//` y `%`.
La librería estándar de Python tiene la función [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod).
Devuelve dos argumentos.
Según la documentación `divmod(a, b)` es equivalente a `(a // b, a % b)`.
Por lo tanto una implementación más limpia de tu algoritmo sería:

```
def sumaDigitos(numero):
    suma = 0
    while numero != 0:
        numero, digito = divmod(numero, 10)
        suma += digito
    return suma
```