# Comprobar si un número contiene un dígito

Tags: python

Tengo un trabajo de la universidad en el que nos pidieron hacer una función para ver si algún dígito del RUT(o DNI) es un 2.

Por ejemplo : el 2, 27 y el 1282 son números que contienen el 2, pero el 184, 1534 y el 109 NO lo contienen.

En este caso sé que lo debería hacer, pero por más que he probado no sé cómo lo debo hacer.
Probé con el módulo, restando, con el len, pero aun así no lo logré.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Matías, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Si prefieres iterar los dígitos de un número de forma puramente matemática, echa un vistazo a esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593194/265345

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tratarlo como cadena de caracteres y utilizar el index = string.find("2"), si te devuelve -1 no encontró el 2, pero si es diferente de -1 si lo encontró. Si esto no funciona por favor denos mas detalles de la problemática para poder apoyarlo mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. No todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu RUT lo tienes guardado como una `str`, eso es un iterable.
Por tanto puedes simplemente comprobar si alguno de sus elementos coincide con el dígito que busques.

```
if "2" in RUT: ...
```

Ten en cuenta que los elementos de un `str` son caracteres, no números.
Por lo tanto para la comprobación no puedes usar un número;
es decir, la condición `if 2 in RUT` siempre será falsa.

Si, por el contrario tu RUT lo tienes guardado como un `int`, puedes convertirlo a `str` y después hacer la misma comprobación.

```
if "2" in str(RUT): ...
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. No todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato En ese caso, reporta mi respuesta.

Comment: No, ya que es la forma correcta de hacerlo, solo hay que tener en cuenta que el responder preguntas que no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio puede incentivar la holgazanería. Saludos.